# Return Optional in a method annotated with @JsonCreator

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I have an enum with a method `@JsonCreator` annotated which returns enum class based on String code, something like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
public enum Gender {

    MALE("M", "Male"), FEMALE("F", "Female");

    private final String code;
    private final String text;

    @JsonCreator
    public static Gender fromValue(String code) {
        for (Gender classType : Gender.values()) {
            if (classType.getCode().equals(code))
                return classType;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

This is working fine, but I would like to return an optional instead of null to avoid any null pointer exceptions in future.

I have searched through Stackoverflow and Jackson documentation, but couldn't find any solution for this.

Is there a way in Jackson to annotate a method returning optional with `@JsonCreator` annotation?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be lookin at it from wrong perspective.

`@JsonCreator` is used either on constructor or factory method - you would not expect constructor optionally return object for you - would you?

On the other hand, if you wrap your enum objects in some DTO class it would probably work out of the box.

```
public class Response {

   private Optional<Gender> gender;

   ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks @sycyhy for your reply, but we prefer not to use Optional for POJO properties, as we have a lot of POJOs with large number of fields, that could create a lot of code if we use optional. We assume that getter methods could return null.